# Kubernetes: how to run a Task periodically inside every Pod of a Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I have read about the various ways to run tasks periodically in a K8s cluster, but none of them seem to work well for this specific case. I have a deployment "my-depl" that can run an arbitrary number of pods and the task needs to execute periodically inside each pod (basically a shell command that "nudges" the main application once a week or so).

The Kubernetes Cronjob functionality starts a task in its own container. This K8s task does not know how many pods are currently running for "my-depl" and cannot run anything in those pods. Conceivably, I could run kubectl within this K8s Cronjob, but that seems incredibly hacky and dangerous.

The second alternative would be to have crond (or an alternative tool like [Jobber](https://github.com/dshearer/jobber) or [Cronenberg](https://github.com/ess/cronenberg)) run as part of the pod. But that would mean that two processes are running and the container might not die, if only the cron process dies.

The third option is to run a multi-process container via a special init process like [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay). This can be made to die if one of the child processes dies, but it seems fairly involved and hardly a first-class feature.

The fourth option I could think of was "don't do this, it's stupid. Redesign your application so it doesn't need to be 'nudged' once a week". That's a sound suggestion, but a lot of work and I need at least a temporary solution in the meantime.

So, does anyone have a better idea than those detailed here?

Comment: What specifically is the action the periodic task needs to perform in order to "nudge" the application?

Comment: The main application needs to be "nudged" to reload its configuration periodically. There's no publically exposable API for that, just an internal API accessible from 'localhost' only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to run `crond` (or an alternative of your choice) in a sidecar container (that is, another container in the same pod). Recall that all containers in a pod share the same network namespace, so `localhost` is the same thing for all containers.

This means your cron container can happily run a `curl` or `wget` command (or whatever else is necessary) to ping your API over the local port.

For example, something like this, in which our cron task simply runs `wget` against the web server running in the `api` container:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  root: |
    * * * * * wget -O /tmp/testfile http://127.0.0.1:8080 2> /tmp/testfile.err
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cron-example
  name: crontabs-ghm86fgddg
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cron-example
  name: cron-example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cron-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cron-example
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
        name: api
      - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          crontab /data/crontabs/root
          exec crond -f -d0
        image: docker.io/alpine:latest
        name: cron
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/crontabs
          name: crontabs
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: crontabs-ghm86fgddg
        name: crontabs
```

Comment: This looks good, but what if the crond container dies, but the api container keeps on running? Will Kubernetes restart the cron container?

Comment: Yes, kubernetes will restart a container if it fails. That behavior is controlled by the Pod's [`restartPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) setting, which defaults to `Always`.

Comment: Unfortunately that apporach does not work in my case, because I need access to the main container's file system. There's all sorts of files there that the "nudge-script" needs, which are supplied by the base image of the main container. So if I copy them out and into the sidecar container, I will lose version control.

I did not know that only "localhost" is shared in terms of networking, but not the filesystem.

Comment: I have now solved this problem by sharing the needed files between sidecar and main container with an emptyDir volume. The main container copies the files to this volume during its startup process.